# Two SQL statements, ignore the return of the first if it has no results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I have a sql statement `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE ....; SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE ....`

What I want is to get the results from the first select statement if it returns results, but if it doesn't, I want to ignore it and just get the results from the second select statement. Is there a way I can do this just using SQL?

I'm getting this returned to me as a datatable, using a dataadapter to fill the datatable from the above SQL statement. I can't change that part, or switch to filling a dataset (for reasons I won't get into, but it just can't be changed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming both queries return the same number and type of columns, one way to do this would be:

```
select * from table1 where ... /* query 1 conditions */
union all
select * from table2 where ... /* query 2 conditions */
and not exists
(select 1 from table1 where ... /* query 1 conditions */)
```

Comment: I like this, but the two statements won't always return similar results, which makes me limited by the columns returned by the first select statement.

Answer (score 0):

A couple options.  You can check the count first:

```
If (select count(*) from table1 where...) > 0
begin
    select * from table1 where...
end
else
begin
    select * from table2 where...
end;
```

if both result sets are identical in structure, you can save the count check (and thus improve performance) by using a temp table:

```
create table #temp (col1 int, col2 varchar(10), ...);

insert #temp
select * from table1 where...;

if @@rowcount = 0 
begin
    insert #temp
    select * from table2 where...
end;

select * from #temp;
```